# Pdf text box markups missing in the converted tiff file (GhostScript)

Tags: pdf, markup, tiff, ghostscript

I am trying to convert pdf to tiff. You can view the pdf in the below link:
[Original pdf](http://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=7736)

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=7736

I currently having Ghostscript 9.02 installed in my system.

I am using the below command to convert the pdf files to tiff.

```
gswin32 -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r300 -sDEVICE=tiffg4
-dPDFFitPage -dGraphicalAlphaBits=1 -dTextAlphaBits=1
-sOutputFile="d:/temp/test/ConvertedPage%06d.tiff"
"d:/temp/test/TextBoxMarkupfile.pdf"
```

There are 3 marked up text box available in the second page. After conversion
those text values are missing in the tiff file.

Is there any options available in the ghostscript to include those text values
in the converted image?

If any workarounds available please suggest me.

Thanks,
Rajesh

Comment: I have the same problem -- GS conversion of PDF to Tiff works great, except for form-field data, which is missing. AAARGH!

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239003/ghostscript-pdf-merging-losing-editable-fields

Answer (score 1):

A [similar question+answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239003/ghostscript-pdf-merging-losing-editable-fields) recommended [pdftk.](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/)

I used a two-step process of [pdf] >> pdftk >> [ImageMagick:](http://www.imagemagick.org/)

```
pdftk original_form.pdf output flattened_form.pdf flatten

convert -define quantum:polarity=min-is-white -endian MSB 
        -units PixelsPerInch -density 204x196 -monochrome 
        -compress Fax -sample 1728 
        "flattened_form.pdf" "final.tif"
```

Since ImageMagick uses GhostScript for pdf conversion it should be possible to use GS directly, but I've gotten better quality from ImageMagick; perhaps I'm not just using the right GS settings.

Comment: Call your `convert` with an additional `-verbose` parameter. Then you will see the exact commandline that ImageMagick uses for its output.

Comment: This worked for me, still works after 9 and a half years